# XSL error: format-number picture: Passive character must not appear between active characters in a sub-picture

Tags: xml, xslt, java-8, saxon, xalan

There is a need to read numbers and format it.

**Input:**

```
<InitialReading>500</InitialReading>
<InitialReading>620,25</InitialReading>
<InitialReading>1 200,5</InitialReading>
<InitialReading>1 100</InitialReading>
```

**XSL:**

```
<xsl:call-template name="formatNumber3">
    <xsl:with-param name="number"
                        select="format-number(number(InitialReading/translate(., ',', '.')), '# ###0.000')"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:template name="formatNumber3">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="formatNumber">
        <xsl:with-param name="number" select="$number"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="format" select="'# ##0,000'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:decimal-format name="SUM_FORMAT" grouping-separator=" " decimal-separator=","/>
<xsl:template name="formatNumber">
    <xsl:param name="number"/>
    <xsl:param name="format"/>
    <xsl:if test="normalize-space($number)">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(normalize-space($number)), $format, 'SUM_FORMAT')"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<p>500,000</p>
<p>620,250</p>
<p>1 200,500</p>
<p>1 100,000</p>
```

**Update:**

`select="format-number(number(InitialReading/translate(., ',', '.')), '##0.000')"`
print **NaN** for the last 2 values. All other values rendered correctly.

The solution needs to be compatible with saxon and xalan implementations.

**Update 2:**

After careful investigation it turned out that *the whitespace character* was actually `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`.

Thanks for help from @Martin Honnen and @Michael Ka, the working snippet looks like:

```
<xsl:variable name="number" select="number(translate(., ', &#160;', '.'))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($number, '# ##0,000', 'SUM_FORMAT')"/>
```

Comment: For which line do you get that error?

Comment: this one `select="format-number(number(InitialReading/translate(., ',', '.')), '# ###0.000')"`

Comment: I guess you need to remove the spaces with e.g. `translate(., ', ', '.')` to ensure you get `1 100` treated as `1100`.

Comment: And it is not clear why you want to use `format-number` twice, I would strongly suggest to parse input once into XPath/XSLT number types, then to use number values throughout any computations and only in final output steps use `format-number` to format a number value in a particular representation.

Comment: `select="InitialReading/translate(., ', ', '.')"`  outputs NaN

Comment: I can't find any such problem at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjhV, perhaps edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples allowing to reproduce the issue, together with details of the XSLT processor used.

Comment: The provided example requires XPath 3.0.

Comment: Well, `InitialReading/translate` is at least using XPath 2.0, so your original code needs an XSLT 2 or 3 processor anyway. But feel free to provide minimal but complete samples of XSLT, XML and output you want plus you get together with exact information about the XSLT processor that gives the error. Asking now for Saxon and Xalan compatibility seems odd given the use of `/translate`. In the end it is not clear why you seem to want to first parse some strings into numbers but then try to format them twice, expecting to be able to pass the result of the first formatting to the second formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me with both XSLT 1 and 3 processor:

```
  <xsl:decimal-format name="SUM_FORMAT" 
    grouping-separator=" " 
    decimal-separator=","/>

  <xsl:template match="InitialReading">
      <xsl:variable name="number"
        select="number(translate(., ', ', '.'))"/>
      <p>Parsed value : <xsl:value-of select="$number"/></p>
      <p>Formatted value: <xsl:value-of select="format-number($number, '# ##0,000', 'SUM_FORMAT')"/></p>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjhV/2:

```
<p>Parsed value : 500</p>
    <p>Formatted value: 500,000</p>
<p>Parsed value : 620.25</p>
    <p>Formatted value: 620,250</p>
<p>Parsed value : 1200.5</p>
    <p>Formatted value: 1 200,500</p>
<p>Parsed value : 1100</p>
    <p>Formatted value: 1 100,000</p>


Parsed value : 500

Formatted value: 500,000

Parsed value : 620.25

Formatted value: 620,250

Parsed value : 1200.5

Formatted value: 1 200,500

Parsed value : 1100

Formatted value: 1 100,000
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here: input and output.

`number()` applied to a string will give you `NaN` if the input string isn't in the correct format for conversion to a number. That means you not only need to translate `","` to `"."`, you also need to get rid of embedded whitespace. You can do that in one go with `translate($in, ", ", ".")`.

For the output, I think your call on `format-number()` should work. I don't know why you're getting the error about the format picture. But you've updated the question several times, so I don't know if you're still getting that error.